# Trouble configuring ssl-redirect on Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have configured an ingress on a kubernetes cluster from Google Cloud. I followed the instructions as is on [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/annotations.md) doc.

My manifest:

```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: web-proxy
    annotations:
      ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  spec:
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - foo.bar.com
      secretName: foo-bar-secret
    rules:
    - host: foo.bar.com
      http:
    paths:
    - backend:
        serviceName: foo-bar-service
        servicePort: 80
      path: /*
```

From the documentation, it specifies that `ssl-redirect`
 is by default `true` if `tls` is configured but it doesn't work. I've also tried to set `force-ssl-redirect` to `true`(default is `false`), still no luck.

I'm confused if there is actually a bug or I'm doing something wrong, because when I run `kubectl describe ing web-proxy`, it displays that annotations were set:

```
Annotations:
  force-ssl-redirect:     true
  [...]
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**
I was using the 1.8.3.gke.0 version but when I upgraded to 1.8.4.gke.0 this seems to have solved the problem.
I'll keep this post updated while I test more annotations(like: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect`)

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, could you please provide more details on that behavior? Are you using nginx as an ingress controller? Do the requests get redirected to the ingress controller at all? (You can check that with the kubectl logs command - there must be an access log).
One thing you might be missing (in case you're using nginx as an ingress controller) is the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` annotation.

Comment: @vdimitrov I'm using a domain that directs the requests towards the ingress allocated IP, then I generated my certs using certbot. I'm using the ingress as is, and from what I understood is that the nginx class is used by default. I have a hunch that it's probably because of the version, because I've read on the forums that people are not having this issue on kubernetes 1.7.4, and I'm using 1.8.4.gke.0 which is available on GCP. I'll give this annotation and see if it works.

Comment: I've had a similar issue where SSL connections always returned 404. The problem with my environment was that the CN of the TLS certificate was not matching the domain.

Comment: @vdimitrov My apologies for something that I wrote incorrect. I was not using the version 1.8.4.gke.0, but 1.8.3.gke.0. I duno why I taught I upgraded, but leaving this asside, now I'm running the 1.8.4.gke.0 and now it's working. I just upgraded a couple of hours ago, and now I'm happy. I don't actually know if the versions 1.8.[0-2].gke had this issue, but it's safe to say that 1.8.4.gke.0 is stable for me now. I still need to test the annotation **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect** if it works. I'll write it down.